# Combine matrix elements

Tags: r, matrix, combinatorics

I wish to get all combinations of elements from a matrix of size m * n.

Sample Example:

```
1   3   5
2   6   7
```

Expected Output:

```
2 , 1
2 , 3
2 , 5
6 , 1
6 , 3
6 , 5
7 , 1
7 , 3
7 , 5
```

The rules:

1. Every combination starts from bottom of matrix and proceeds towards top. It may switch columns though.
2. Every combination should have number of elements equal to number of rows.
3. A combination can't have an element from the same row present twice.
4. Number of columns and rows could vary. So solution has to be generic.

I tried doing this but not getting the exact result

```
m <- rbind(c(1, 3, 5), c(2, 6, 7))
do.call(expand.grid, split(m, rep(nrow(m):1, ncol(m))))
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Please take some time revising [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). In short, SO is not a free tutorial/homework service. We are happy to help provided you demonstrate your own effort at solving the problem. Please revise your question to include your code attempt.

Comment: Perhaps you can show your attempt with `expand.grid`.

Comment: m <- rbind(c(1,3,5),c(2,6,7))

do.call(expand.grid, split(m, rep(nrow(m):1, ncol(m))))

Comment: its not a homework or anything.. i came accross this problem and was figuring out how to do this in r

Comment: @Nrj Please don't post critical clarifications as comments. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53008210/edit) your post to include (1) your code attempt, and (2) a clear description of where you got stuck and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways,

```
do.call(
    rbind,lapply(m[2,], function(x){ cbind(x, c(m[1,])) })
)
```

data:

```
m<-
structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 7L), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3")))
```

result:

```
#   x  
#V1 2 1
#V2 2 3
#V3 2 5
#V1 6 1
#V2 6 3
#V3 6 5
#V1 7 1
#V2 7 3
#V3 7 5
```

---

general solution:

```
do.call(
    rbind,lapply(m[nrow(m),], function(x){ cbind(x, c(m[-nrow(m),])) })
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much .

Comment: but what if its like 3*3 or a 4*4 matrix?

Comment: Its unclear how your logic transfers to higher dimension. You will have to provide more **example data** and more **expected outputs**. Don't expect to get a general universal solution by providing minimal input.

Comment: m <- rbind(c(1,3,5),c(2,6,7),c(7,8,9))

and the output be like

7,2
7,6
7,7
7,1
7,3
7,5
8,2
8,6
8,7
8,1
8,3
8,5
9,2
9,6
9,7
9,1
9,3
9,5

Comment: [Please don't post critical clarifications as comments. Edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53008210/combine-matrix-elements#comment92920203_53008210)